# storing result of awk in shell script

Tags: shell

I am new to shell script and I have started it today itself. Can anyone tell me how to store and retrieve the output of this command:

> cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz" | awk '/cpu MHz/ {print $4}'

This command returns just four decimal numbers but I am struggling to store these four numbers.
I have tried to store them in array but it has not been fruitful for me. Please help!!

Comment: `it has not been fruitful for me` - what does that mean? Please show what have you tried.

Comment: I have tried $speed=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz" | awk '/cpu MHz/ {print $4}'`. Then I try to print ${speed[0]}. It just prints all the four numbers seperated by space. But speed[1] returns nothing.

Comment: What's the point of the grep, when the awk behind it applies a more restrictive pattern?

Comment: Anyhow, yeah, you're assigning a regular string, not an array. When you try to access a string as if it were an array, it presents with all the data only in the first element.

Comment: `readarray -t cpus < <(awk '/cpu MHz/ { print $4}' </proc/cpuinfo)` will store all your results in the array named `cpus`; you can see them with `declare -p cpus`, or iterate over them with something like `for cpu in "${cpus[@]}"; do echo "CPU speed: $cpu"; done`

Comment: (that code's a lot more efficient, too; no reason to run all three of `cat`,`grep` and `awk`, all three of which are separate executables rather than built-in components of the shell, when one could do with only `awk`).